# Large networks do not render

Tags: cytoscape.js

I've been using cytoscape.js extensively to render several networks. It seems to work fine for small networks, however it fails with larger ones (173 nodes and 214 edges).

I had a look at Firebug console and it looks as follows:

```
TypeError: E._private.edges is undefined
http://localhost/WS/biojs-jmv/biojs/src/main/resources/dependencies/cytoscape/2.0.2/cytoscape.min.js
Line 125

Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
http://localhost/WS/biojs-jmv/biojs/src/main/resources/dependencies/cytoscape/2.0.2/cytoscape.min.js
Line 259

TypeError: H._private.style.shape is undefined
http://localhost/WS/biojs-jmv/biojs/src/main/resources/dependencies/cytoscape/2.0.2/cytoscape.min.js
Line 259
```

Can it be that I'm I missing something due to configuration? or maybe a library bug?

EDIT:

I updated the library version to 2.0.4. However the problem still persists when rendering large networks. These are the errors that firebug reports:

```
TypeError: E._private.edges is undefined
http://localhost/WS/biojs-jmv/biojs/src/main/resources/dependencies/cytoscape/2.0.4/cytoscape.min.js
Line 147

TypeError: d._private.style.shape is undefined
http://localhost/WS/biojs-jmv/biojs/src/main/resources/dependencies/cytoscape/2.0.4/cytoscape.min.js
Line 244
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (most likely old) bug seems to be with the style rather than the size of the graph.  Have you tried v2.0.4?